# Laravel7.x Commands: how to route to a url from command file's handle() method?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller, command

How to route to another url with a parameter from laravel's `app/console/commands/myCommand.php's` handler() method?

I want to route to another url/page/route with a parameter from handle() method of custom made command file which(route) later will call a controller and that parameter passed by handle() via route() will be handle() there in controller.

```
app/console/commands/myCommand.php

public function handle()
    {
        $sale_days = SaleDay::latest()->first();
        Log::info('test command file');

        $latest_date = $sale_days->date;
        // $request = Request::create('/game/end/day/'.$latest_date, 'get');
        // '<a href=' . route('game.endday', $latest_date) . '></a>';
        // return $request;
        return redirect()->to('game.endday', $latest_date);
    }
```

```
web.php

    Route::get('/game/end/day/{date}', 'SaleDayController@endday')->name('game.endday');
```

```
controller 

public function endday($date) {

    // $date = \Artisan::call('auto_day:close');
    Log::info("command endday module in saledaycontroller");
    $new_Date=Carbon::create($date);
    $prev_sale_day=$this->daySaleService->endDay($date);
    
    $new_sale_day=$this->daySaleService->firstOrCreate($new_Date->addDays(1));
    $this->daySaleService->changeCurrentDay($new_sale_day->id);
    $this->daySaleService->shiftDayGameSales($new_sale_day->id,$prev_sale_day->id);
    Log::info("command endday module in saledaycontroller ENDDDDD");

    return redirect()->route('game.sale');
}
```

the handle function is not working properly, How can I route from handle() method with a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terrible idea.  You would be better served either abstracting the code in your controller to the service and then calling that service in both the command and the controller.

Or alternatively trigger an event in the controller and command, and have a listener for that event that executes your logic.

Comment: using command I cannot access the `Auth::User()` which is necessary to do in my case, but now I wanna click a button in laravel view automatically on specific time. I want to load a route or controller at specific time in laravel automatically

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this

```
app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class)->handle(YourRequest);
```

Comment: On this it says, No scheduled commands are ready to run.

Comment: If you just wanna run as a command, do not extends ScheduleRunCommand, just extends Command.

Comment: how? I want to load  `Route::get('/game/end/day/{date}', 'SaleDayController@endday')->name('game.endday');` this route from handle() method of myCommand along with a parameter

Comment: ```app()->make(HttpKernel::class)->handle(Request::create('/game/end/day/putyourdateparamhere','GET',[your other params]));```   
And the error "No scheduled commands" is because of your "myCommand" extends `ScheduleRunCommand `, you should extends `Command` instead.

Comment: Extending Command already `class AutoDayClose extends Command` 
[github link](https://github.com/zowhair/gul/tree/localDev) . please take a look to help me solve. files: `kernel.php` `AutoDayClose.php` and `SaleDayController` and route is  `Route::get('/game/end/day/{date}', 'SaleDayController@endday')->name('game.endday');` in web.php
still getting **no schedule command  are ready to run**

Comment: My bad, try `\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class` instead.

Comment: using  `app()->make(HttpKernel::class)->handle(Request::create('/game/end/day/'.$latest_date,'GET'));`  this in `handle()` method. Which says same ** no schedule command are ready to run** on running `php artisan schedule:run` from terminal

Comment: I am getting some error on sending request from command file's handle() method `Object of class Illuminate\Http\Request could not be converted to int {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Object of class Illuminate\\Http\\Request could not be converted to int at ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:134)`